# How to know if I am behind a VPN

Tags: networking, 14.04, vpn

I am currently trying to connect to VPN network of my company on 14.04 and wanted to know if there is any way to know that I am currently connected to the VPN.

I have tried to find my public IP and do an WHOIS lookup to check if my Company owns the IP, and I have found that it works.

Is there any better way to check up if I am connected to VPN?

Comment: Google "what is my ip" without quotes. before and after VPN connection. If your external IP changes, you are connected.

Comment: [icanhazip](http://www.icanhazip.com) also works great for checking your public IP

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that a straight, uncomplicated answer is that if you can see your companies internal servers and resources, you are connected to their VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You can ping your VPN gateway. So, if your gateway on the VPN is say 172.20.1.1, the exit status of ping -c 1 -W 10 172.20.1.1 will tell you if you're connected.

You can also utilize third party software like VPNCheck. It helps you to feel safe if your VPN connection breaks, this is done by shutting down your main network connection or programs of your choice and showing a notification box. Basically it constantly looks for a change in your VPN network adapter.And you can connect to either PPTP or L2TP with it.